# Changing the endpoint displayed in browser for Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my Spring Boot application. Now when I try to access a secured endpoint, it redirects to the "/login" endpoint which is the expected behaviour. At this point, the URL in the browser is "http://example.com/login".

What I want to do is change this "/login" such that URL looks something like "http://example.com/app/login". The rest of the Spring Security part should work exactly as before. Just the URL which is displayed in the browser should be changed.

This is my WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    /**
     * Logger object for logging
     */
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
        this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/app/login").permitAll()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                        String redirectURL = requestURL.substring(0,
                                requestURL.length() - request.getRequestURI().length());
                        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL + "/main");

                    }
                }).failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login?error");
                    }
                }).and().cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS).sessionFixation()
                .changeSessionId();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    // Builds the authentication provider object for the authentication manager
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

I have an endpoint defined in my controller which looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/app/login")
public String loginUI(Model model) {
        return "login";
}
```

My custom login page "login.html" is present inside **src/main/resources/views/login.html**

This is the login.html file

```
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head th:include="layout :: head(title=~{::title},links=~{})">
    <title>Please Login</title>
  </head>
  <body th:include="layout :: body" th:with="content=~{::content}">
    <div th:fragment="content">
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">               
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please Login</legend>
                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
                    Invalid username and password.
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
                    You have been logged out.
                </div>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>        
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>    
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I try to access a secured endpoint, it does redirect to "/app/login" and the browser shows that too. However, a 404 error is returned.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: one of the things you need is `@EnableWebSecurity` and can you please include the controller class with your endpoint and not just the endpoint

Comment: Did you implement any custom ViewResolver? If so, please post the code..